# how to put a login function in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

here i am trying to do a login but it all the times it navigate to the page though username and password are wrong

here is my login controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Login;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {
        return view('login/login');
    }


    public function show()
    {
        return view('login/login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $uname = Input::get('username');
        $pwd = Input::get('password');
        echo "$uname";
        echo "$pwd";
    }
}
```

here is my .env

```
 APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Zm3uZ82dtjozo68rs2cGAlXXmzj9EuueqCcKsC73VTo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

if i am trying to modify this connect to different table and try to compare values but in my actual db i dint have any table like that
and five the error message like this 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test1.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from users where userName = admin limit 1)

here in my db my table name is login not users

Comment: you should check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, why u dont use make:auth? Then u can change login data from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line.

```
protected $table='login';
```

To your App/User.php file, because it uses users table and with the "protected $table='login';" you tell Laravel what table to use. You have to be careful how you name files in Laravel.